# How can I create a Snow Leopard upto El Captain OSX live USB flash drive?

Tags: macos, usb, install, snow-leopard

I want to create a USB flash drive with an installed copy of Snow Leopard upto El Captain , so I can run any MacOS version from Snow Leopard up to El Captain directly from a USB flash drive(similar to Linux live USB or a live CD). Ideally I can use one single flash drive for all versions, but using one per version is also ok.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145927/discussion-on-question-by-updownallaround-how-can-i-create-a-snow-leopard-upto-e); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.